Problematic frame: # C [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xd4f568]
STS-4.21.1 just started crashing when on-hover window is triggered; the crash is at:
# C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xd4f568]

STS-4.22.0 is also affected:
# C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0+0xd600d8]

Fault
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ce1be14f568, pid=26351, tid=26352
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (21.0.2+13) (build 21.0.2+13-58)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (21.0.2+13-58, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xd4f568]
#

Stack
Stack: [0x000078a626100000,0x000078a626200000],  sp=0x000078a6261fd8c0,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xd4f568]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 5135  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk3.GTK3.gtk_main_iteration_do(Z)Z (0 bytes) @ 0x000078a61081df79 [0x000078a61081df20+0x0000000000000059]
J 32226 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z (88 bytes) @ 0x000078a6119dce0c [0x000078a6119dcd20+0x00000000000000ec]
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run()V+564
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;[I)V+382
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda+0x000078a5b025a048.run()V+12
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+16
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+113
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+138
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+79
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+99
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+132
j  java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+11 java.base@21.0.2
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000078a5b0019800.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+54 java.base@21.0.2
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x000078a5b0002c00.invokeExact_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+22 java.base@21.0.2
j  jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invokeImpl(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+72 java.base@21.0.2
j  jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+23 java.base@21.0.2
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+102 java.base@21.0.2
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+201
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+159
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x000078a60ff37cc6

Environment
## Hardware Information:
Hardware Model:               Dell Inc. XPS 13 9310
Memory:                       8.0 GiB
Processor:                    11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 × 8
Graphics:                     Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                256.1 GB

## Software Information:
Firmware Version:             3.22.0
OS Name:                      Ubuntu 23.10
OS Build:                     (null)
OS Type:                      64-bit
GNOME Version:                Not Available
Windowing System:             Wayland
Kernel Version:               Linux 6.5.0-27-generic


This is a known bug, likely due to an unresolved hardware acceleration bug, that has been addressed for the upcoming 2024-06 (4.32) release scheduled for June 12, 2024:

eclipse.platform.swt #179
eclipse.platform.swt #1146

In my case, this was apparently triggered from an OS update of the WebKit library. As noted in the issues by Dave Moten, a workaround is to disable WebKit's DMA buffer renderer:
WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1

by, for example, setting this in your launch script:
jan@jan-lite:~/Desktop$ cat SpringToolSuite-4.22.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=env WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1 /home/jan/sts-4.22.0.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4
Name=Spring Tool Suite 4.22
GenericName=STS
Comment=STS with WebKit GTK acceleration disabled
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;
Icon=/home/jan/sts-4.22.0.RELEASE/icon.xpm

Upcoming releases of Eclipse will fold-in this workaround by disabling hardware acceleration.

Both mentioned bugs are closed. Under what conditions does this issue occur and what is the final solution that no longer requires the workaround you mentioned? You mean, as noted by Dave Moten (@dave-moten), right?

I've added a note about the incorporated workaround @howlger. ANd, not sure if your second point is taking issue with my original attribution, but I've tweaked that a bit as well.

Thanks for the edits, making your answer helpful to me.
